# Difference between ansible yum list?

Tags: ansible, centos7, yum

I am trying to output a list of installed yum packages before and after running the `yum update` command in ansible. However, I note that for the list parameter, there are other options such as `installed`, `updates`, `available` and `repos`. May I know what is the difference between these options?

Comment: I don't use linux much I'm a mac use however I checked http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html#LIST_OPTIONS, I think a does a pretty good job explaining what the various options do. Maybe you might want to check it out.

Comment: That's a great link! Thanks for listing down the link, it does help me understand better too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is making reference to the options avaialble in the "yum" package managenent. So easier way to know the difference is by referencing to "yum" documentation itself (or man page), as "yum" ansible module only uses its capabilities.

list - As ansible module doc explains, it is the equivalent to "yum list --show-duplicates "

installed - Will list the yum installed packages in the host

updates - Will return a list with the packages to be updated

available - Lists available packages.

repos - Will list the subscribed repos for the host.

You can always see the difference by yourself even using ad-hoc commands and visually exploring the output, like this.

```
ansible kube_workers -m yum -a 'list=repos'
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I did also refer to https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_yum_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print-1.pdf. But i wasn't sure which was mapped to what. So in context of say google play store, updates meant apps that have updates available, available meant all the apps that are currently available in the play store? Sorry I do not quite understand what subscribed repos means. I tried to run the playbook with different commands but I couldn't tell what is the difference as I am new to yum and ansible.

Comment: Imagine you have not one, but different "play stores". You can think of repos as "play stores". You can subscribe to none, some or all "play stores" (repos). Each repo, will have a set of packages, hence "optional", "epel", etc. Once you subscribe a system to a specific repo, you'll have "avaialble" packages to install and then update. In this context, "available" will show you ALL the packages from all your repos, either to update or install if you still don't have them. Makes sense? Also, it may be easier to see what you want with "ad-hoc" commands (like the example used)instead of playbooks